# Link "set tag preferences" broken

Tags: bug, status-completed

The link "set tag preferences" on my frontpage is broken. It seems the "set tag preferences" link only shows up when you haven't selected favorite tags, but still have a frequented tag. I can't get the link to show up on other stackexhange sites.

[image]

- The link: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/8957?tab=prefs
- Where it leads: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/8957/mindworx?tab=prefs
- Where it should lead: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/8957

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was fixed rather a while ago, and there are currently no references to the old user preference tab in the source.

Comment: I'll take your word for this, as I can't check it, since I don't have the frequented tags anymore and have added my own custom preferred tags.